# Visual studio code: how to automatically close a self closing tag from a the matching closing tag

Tags: visual-studio-code

Say I have a tag like so `<span></span>`. And I want to do `<span/>` and have vscode automatically remove the "`</span>`". How can I do this?

This functionality was something I had in Jetbrains products and I miss it dearly. I think I had it in sublime text days as well? I've been hunting online for days now and I can not find a solution.